# Kibana: Pie Chart slices based on beginning value of field only

Tags: kibana, visualization

I am trying to visualize field data but based on the first 3 characters within the string. Say the field contains "+44123456", I want the pie chart to visualize based on "+44" only.

Please assist me in achieving this with advanced JSON field ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it via using the "Advanced JSON" input field :

Try following script :

```
{
    "script": "( _value.indexOf(' ') > 0 ? _value.substring(_value.lastIndexOf(' ')) : _value )"
}
```